# Giving access to (read / write) to other users on nfs without root previliges

Tags: linux, centos-7, nfs

I am working on a CentOS server without root privileges. I am trying to share a specific folder on the network with another user.

I have already tried 'setfacl' with no success (resulting in 'Operations not supported').

Can someone tell me how can i give either read/write access to folders when I don't have root privileges ??

Comment: Is the folder _currently_ being accessed via NFS, or is it local to you? (What does `df -T thefolder` show?) If it's local – what filesystem type is it on?

Comment: The folder is on the network mount. `df -T folder` gives 
```FileSystem              Type   1k-blocks Used% Mounted on

some.com:/path/    nfs       123123   83%    /path/to/mount/point```

Comment: Can you check with `findmnt -u /path/to/mtpt` whether it's NFSv3 or some version of NFSv4.x?

Comment: `findmnt -u /path/. `
gives
`rw,realtime,vers=3,rsize=223,wsize=121231,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,mountaddr=...,mountvers=3,mountport=300,mountproto=udp,local_lock=none,addr=...`

Answer (score 0):

Your NFS mount uses `vers=3` meaning NFSv3, which does not support any ACL configuration as far as I know. You will need the server admin's assistance, either to set ACLs directly on the server through SSH or to create a *group* and add users to it (allowing chgrp and chmod to be used).

---

ACL support would require NFSv4, which has its own ACL system different from POSIX (but very similar to the one in SMB/NTFS). The Linux NFSv4 servers will translate between POSIX ACLs on disk and NFSv4 ACLs on the network, although the Linux NFS *client* unfortunately doesn't do the opposite translation. So if NFSv4 were in use, you would need to use tools that work with NFSv4 ACLs – i.e. `nfs4_getfacl` and `nfs4_setfacl` from the "nfs4-acl-tools" package (or wherever CentOS puts them) – instead of the usual POSIX ACL tools.

For example, to add an ACL entry that allows read+execute access, it would be similar to:

```
# Add the equivalent of a "u:someuser:rx" ACL
nfs4_setfacl -a "A::someuser@example.com:RX" myfolder

# Add the equivalent of a "d:u:someuser:rx" ACL (default aka inheritable)
nfs4_setfacl -a "A:fdi:someuser@example.com:RX" myfolder
```

Comment: Not Sure if I can get that done via admins.
Is it possible to give read access via 'chown' or 'chmod' for nfs v3?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask the help of an administrator.
The non-root user doing the `mount` needs to be authorized
to do so by an administrator.

There are two methods (which your administrator should know already):

- Add an entry to `/etc/fstab` for the desired share
- Add the user to the `suders` file, specifying use of the
  `mount` command.

For more information see the post
[Redhat: non-root user needs to copy files to a NFS share](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66126/17660).
The administrator can set the share to be read-only.